# Cannot Install Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Eclipse: Missing Requirement Error

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-marketplace

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Eclipse. During the installation process, an error is thrown indicating a missing requirement. The installation is looking for org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui within a specific version range [3.7.0,4.0.0), which it seems unable to find. Here's the exact error message:

Cannot complete the provisioning operation. Please change your selection and try again. See below for details.
Missing requirement: Spring IDE Configuration Graphical Editing 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found

I've checked my software sources and tried to find resolutions online without success. It's unclear whether this is a compatibility issue with the current version of Eclipse I am using or a problem with the update site configuration. Any insights or solutions to resolve this dependency issue would be greatly appreciated.

What I tried:

I attempted to install the Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Eclipse using the Eclipse Marketplace. I navigated to the Marketplace from within Eclipse, searched for the Spring Tools 3 Add-On, and initiated the installation process.

What I expected to happen:

I expected the installation process to complete successfully without any errors, as I had followed the standard procedure for installing plugins from the Eclipse Marketplace.

What actually happened:

The installation failed with an error message indicating a missing requirement. Specifically, the installer could not find the org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui package within the version range [3.7.0,4.0.0). The error message was as follows:

Cannot complete the provisioning operation. Please change your selection and try again. See below for details.
Missing requirement: Spring IDE Configuration Graphical Editing 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found

Despite the error, I verified that my Eclipse instance is up to date, and I have an active internet connection. I also checked the available software sites in the Eclipse installation to ensure they include the necessary repositories for Spring Tool Suite and Mylyn.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTd5Q.png)

Comment: "I've checked my software sources"--what are they?

Answer (score 1):

The [***Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4***](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-3-add-spring-tools-4) is **end of life**. See the [description in the Eclipse Marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-3-add-spring-tools-4#details):

> **End of life: This Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4 is no longer maintained or updated. The final and last release is 3.9.22,
> which corresponds to the Spring Tools 4.14.1 release for Eclipse
> 2022-03. There will be no updates to newer Spring Tools 4 or newer
> Eclipse versions anymore. Please upgrade to Spring Tools 4 instead.**

The last supported version was Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23), which is already a couple of releases behind (as you can see by clicking on the download icon). It might work with newer versions, but there is no guarantee.

According to the error message, the plugin `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui` of version 3.7.0 or higher, but lower than 4.0.0 is required, but cannot be found. The current version of this required plugin is already 4.1.0 which means it wont work with the latest version of Eclipse Mylyn. Maybe it will work with Mylyn 3.26 (if you want to try it, in the preferences *Install/Update > Available Software Sites* you need to add the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.26/`](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.26/) containing the required plugin in version 3.26.0).

Comment: If you are missing some specific features of the Spring Tools 3 Add-On when using the Spring Tools 4 exclusively, please let us know and file an enhancement request.